# Node.js says it can't load sqlite3 module, but does anyway

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm

I'm working with the new [Node.js Tools for Visual Studio](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/) and included the [sqlite3 npm module](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3).  When I call `require('sqlite3')` it throws the error:

`Error: Cannot find module './binding\Debug\node-v11-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'`

Odd thing is, when I ignore the error and continue running the code, everything works fine...until the function I'm in returns; then the server crashes.

Has anyone else had this issue?  I have a suspicion that it has something to do with the `./binding` part, but wouldn't know where to begin in terms of finding out why.

Comment: Do you have [`node-gyp`](https://npmjs.org/package/node-gyp) installed as a global package? Native addons like `sqlite3` will need it to install properly.

Comment: I didn't.  But just installed it, reinstalled the sqlite3 package, and no change.  I also tried wrapping the `require` call in a try/catch; doesn't even catch the error.

Comment: You could try to explicitly install an older version from npm next time.

Comment: You see it? https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Building-On-Windows

Comment: I fixed this by downgrading my Node version from 12 to 10.

Comment: https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3 is a better library

Answer (score 67, accepted):

use this:-

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source
```

Comment: Correct answer. This builds it in the used environment architecture.

Comment: This did not work for me but the below tarball install worked. Odd.

Comment: Not good. You get a bunch of compilation errors in someone else's code, instead of the package manager just installing the dependency.

Comment: This did not work for me at all. I got  huge list of Err and Deprecated messages and then it quits.

Answer (score 37):

This is what worked for me: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3

```
npm install https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/tarball/master
```

Comment: This just worked for me as well ( mac 10.10.3 ) . Any idea why ?

Comment: Me as well. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Works on win 10.

Answer (score 2):

From: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Building-On-Windows

1. Install required software:
2. **Python 2.x**: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/
3. **Win SDK**: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displayLang=en&id=8279
4. **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010+**: https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=48217
5. Build:
6. `npm install sqlite`
7. `npm install`
8. `node-gyp configure build`

Comment: The second link, win sdk, does not work when clicking download.

Comment: @Timo Post updated with a new URL. Please test with it and let us known if it is working.

Comment: Do you know if once you can use `python 3` which is already installed on my box. I used the solution from Demodave that works. Maybe it is similar to your steps with just one command, `python` and `win sdk` needed?? However, my `node_modules` folder is now after installing `node-sqlite` 100 mb in size, so not much load it seems for additional software like `sdk`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the kind of problem, my `node` version is v10.16.3
This globally installed sqlite3 gives error in loading by `require('sqlite3')`

It been solved by install a sqlite3 local to project.

```
$ npm install sqlite3
```

Note without -g option, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a problem with the `sqlite3` npm package itself.  There exists a `lib\binding\Release\` folder, but not a `lib\binding\Debug\` folder.  I just created a copy of the `Release` folder, named it `Debug`, and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

In case this above has not worked for anyone, here is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt install node-sqlite3
```

(I am using Ubuntu with Vscode as editor). It seems installing this node-sqlite3 module was the one that was recognized.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the root cause was a Dockerfile specifying `npm` when it needed to be `yarn` for cross OS compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

To skip searching for pre-compiled binaries, and force a build from source, use

```
npm install --build-from-source
```

Comment: Not good. You get a bunch of compilation errors in someone else's code, instead of the package manager just installing the dependency.